# Javascript timeout error: Result not received in 60 seconds

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I'm trying to hit on search button on a webpage using the following code using Excel VBA Editor

obj.ExecuteScript("document.getelementbyclassname("XYZ").[0].click();")

and getting the javascript timeout error. Please suggest a way to handle this?

Comment: Please include you code as ***text***, formatted as a `code block`, not as linked images. Those trying to help can then copy/paste it into their own development environments to try to help you.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow !! please read [mcve] and edit your post accordingly

Comment: Also make sure you share the code block that you are trying to execute and complete error message.